# Where does Hudson store its last synchronized Perforce changelist number?

Tags: hudson, perforce, hudson-plugins

One of our Hudson build systems is not automatically starting its jobs since we switched it over to a different Perforce server. The polling log reports:

```
Last sync'd change was nnnnnn
```

Where `nnnnnn` is a changelist number from the old server. The new server has lower CL numbers, which causes the problem.

How do I adjust the CL number that Hudson compares against?

Comment: When you changed the build.xml, was Hudson down at that time? If not did you restart Hudson or reloaded the config immediately after the changes were made?

Comment: Thanks! Sometimes it's the most obvious things...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The changelist number is kept in the *build.xml* file in the Hudson job's *lastSuccessful* directory. Replace the `<changeNumber>` element's content with an appropriate value, then restart Hudson.